# Revising image without other changes to Answer text

Tags: support, images

I've noticed [a graph I'd posted in an Answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/392585/3111) (an uploaded .png) has a typo in the legend (had "ploy" for "poly" in one entry, should it get fixed before you read this).

Forseeing that this particular Answer would involve a bit of trial and error, I had made it Community Wiki from the outset.  However the prospect of fixing the image got me wondering if one could overwrite the underlying imgur link and thereby fix the "typo" without editing the Answer per se.

No doubt having some revision history is good to refer to, but I worry a little about the storage wasted by the discarded image.

Comment: I don't know of a way to overwrite or delete images that have been uploaded to imgur from SE. If there is something like that, it would be nice to know (although I've lost a large number of the image URLs that I've replaced). I wonder if imgur keeps a record of the SE account that uploaded an image.

Answer (score 2):

SE users do not have direct access to the [imgur installation for SE](http://stack.imgur.com/). But they can request SE team delete a particular image if there is a good reason: for example, the image contains confidential information that should not have been included. See

- [Can I / should I delete unused images from Imgur?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/94710)
- [Is it possible to delete images from SO server once they've been added to an answer?](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/482)

I don't think they would delete an image just to save storage space. Even the $2/month pro accounts get [unlimited storage](https://imgur.com/register/upgrade) at imgur. Presumably, the [SE-imgur contract](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94286) pays imgur more than that.